# Camel + MyBatis + Apache Aries

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, mybatis, aries

I'm following the setup guide located at: [Camel MyBatis Integration Guide](http://camel.apache.org/mybatis.html). I am using Service Mix 5.0.1. I used features-install spring-mybatis which pulled in 3.2.4.RELEASE. My SqlMapConfig file only contains information about the typeHandlers and typeAliases.

When I start service mix and then start my app I receive the following stack trace:

```
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Errorsetting property: PropertyDescriptor <name: configLocation, getter: null, setter: [class org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(interface org.springframework.core.io.Resource)]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperty(BeanRecipe.java:941)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:907)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:888)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:820)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:787)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)[:1.7.0_45]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.RefRecipe.internalCreate(RefRecipe.java:62)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:106)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperty(BeanRecipe.java:933)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:907)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:888)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:820)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:787)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)[:1.7.0_45]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:245)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:183)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:681)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:378)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:269)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:276)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:245)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.modifiedBundle(BlueprintExtender.java:235)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:500)[11:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:433)[11:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$AbstractTracked.track(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:725)[11:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:463)[11:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$BundleEventHook.event(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:422)[11:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.invokeBundleEventHook(SecureAction.java:1103)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.createWhitelistFromHooks(EventDispatcher.java:695)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:483)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4244)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1923)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:944)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:931)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
at org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi.StartBundle.doExecute(StartBundle.java:37)[39:org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi:2.3.4]
at org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:37)[39:org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi:2.3.4]
at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.OsgiCommandSupport.execute(OsgiCommandSupport.java:38)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.commands.basic.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:35)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:78)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:474)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:400)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.Console.run(Console.java:183)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.DelayedStarted.run(DelayedStarted.java:79)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
*Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to convert value /META-INF/SqlMapConfig.xml to type interface org.springframework.core.io.Resource. Type interface org.springframework.core.io.Resource is an interface or an abstract class* 
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.AggregateConverter.createObject(AggregateConverter.java:310)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.AggregateConverter.convertFromString(AggregateConverter.java:304)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.AggregateConverter.convert(AggregateConverter.java:174)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.convert(BlueprintRepository.java:402)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils$PropertyDescriptor.convert(ReflectionUtils.java:394)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils$MethodPropertyDescriptor.internalSet(ReflectionUtils.java:628)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils$PropertyDescriptor.set(ReflectionUtils.java:378)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperty(BeanRecipe.java:939)[8:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
```

... 50 more

My Bean definitions are as follows:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
  <argument>
    <bean class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
      <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
      <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@intersting-ip:port:schema"/>
      <property name="user" value="user"/>
      <property name="password" value="password"/>
    </bean>
  </argument>
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
  <property name="configLocation" value="/META-INF/SqlMapConfig.xml"/>
  <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:META-INF/mappers/**/*.xml"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mybatis" class="org.apache.camel.component.mybatis.MyBatisComponent">
  <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

**Updating config and new error**

**Updated Configuration:**

```
<bean id="myBatis" class="org.apache.camel.component.mybatis.MyBatisComponent">
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="mybatisConfig" class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">
    <argument value="classpath*:META-INF/SqlMapConfig.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
    <argument>
        <bean class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
            <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@intersting-ip:port:schema"/>
            <property name="user" value="user"/>
            <property name="password" value="password"/>
        </bean>
    </argument>
</bean>

<!-- Without this, the creation of myBatis will bomb out stating that org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean is not an instance of org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory -->
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory" factory-ref="sqlSessionFactoryBean" factory-method="getObject" />

<bean id="sqlSessionFactoryBean" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="cctvDataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation" ref="mybatisConfig"/>
    <property name="mapperLocations">
        <array value-type="org.springframework.core.io.Resource">
            <bean class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">
                <argument value="classpath*:META-INF/mappers/**/*.xml" />
            </bean>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Updated Error**

```
2014-08-06 10:46:20,824 | ERROR | mix\5.0.1/deploy | BlueprintContainerImpl | ?? | 7 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.0 | Unable to start blueprint container for bundle project org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Error when instantiating bean sqlSessionFactory of class interface org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory
....
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [classpath*:META-INF/SqlCookConfig.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
  at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
  at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.buildSqlSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:358)
 at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SqlSessio
```

nFactoryBean.java:340)

Answer (score 1):

The guide you are using is for spring not [Aries blueprint](http://aries.apache.org/modules/blueprint.html) and this is the main source of the problem. [mybatis-spring](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/index.html) is used for integration and it uses spring specific things.

The problem is with `configLocation` property of `SqlSessionFactoryBean`. It should be spring `org.springframework.core.io.Resource`. Spring can automatically convert string to `Resource` if you [use prefix](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.5/reference/resources.html#resources-resource-strings) to give a hint.
 Aries knows nothing about spring and doesn't have built in converter from `String` to spring `Resource`.

There are two options how to tackle this:

1. inject `Resource` implementing bean to `SqlSessionFactoryBean` instead of string
2. implement your own `org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.Converter` which will take string and return `Resource` implementation. The converter should be added to context as regular bean and it will be used by Aries for conversion when needed. In this case definition of `SqlSessionFactoryBean` is not changed.

In both cases you may use `org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource` or implement `Resource` yourself.

Comment: #1 does not work. It still claims the files are not located, even with the string: 'classpath*:META-INF/SqlMapConfig.xml' -- I tried variants without the * and a preceding /. Looking into option two a bit further.

Comment: You can't get the same error if you inject implementation of Resource. What error do you get and what is you configuration?

Comment: You need to specify full pathname like /META-INF/SqlMapConfig.xml without classpath or * prefix

Comment: Was pulled other directions today, removing classpath:* did not help. I'm actually still told that META-INF/SqlMapConfig.xml does not exist, even though it's configured to use a / in front. I'll see about adding a repo on github which reproduces.

Comment: Looks like you are creating a Spring Aries Blueprint to be deployed as a servicemix bundle. In this case , the blueprint.xml will have your service references, i'm assuming that you are declaring the spring beans in the same file, is this correct. In the event that are you're blueprint is separate and you are separate spring application-context files, then i'd recommend the creation of the context files for spring in /META-INF/spring the reason being that camel-spring can load them sans issue in this case.