# Camel-Mybatis Open session Exception

Tags: java, apache-camel, mybatis, spring-mybatis, camel-blueprint

I'm using Camel-Mybatis version 2.12.0.redhat-610379, when we trying to start the bundle thru karaf container the following exception throws. Please advice.

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
```

#### Error opening session.  Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException

#### Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException

```
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:23)[280:org.mybatis.mybatis:3.2.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory.openSessionFromDataSource(DefaultSqlSessionFactory.java:88)[280:org.mybatis.mybatis:3.2.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory.openSession(DefaultSqlSessionFactory.java:43)[280:org.mybatis.mybatis:3.2.5]
    at org.apache.camel.component.mybatis.MyBatisProducer.process(MyBatisProducer.java:51)[282:org.apache.camel.camel-mybatis:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:110)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:279)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler.process(DefaultErrorHandler.java:56)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:166)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processByErrorHandler(TransactionErrorHandler.java:218)[150:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:99)[150:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:112)[150:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processByErrorHandler(TransactionErrorHandler.java:218)[150:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler$1.doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionErrorHandler.java:181)[150:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.doInTransaction(TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.java:33)[149:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-tx:3.2.9.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:131)[149:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-tx:3.2.9.RELEASE_1]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.doInTransactionTemplate(TransactionErrorHandler.java:174)[150:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processInTransaction(TransactionErrorHandler.java:134)[150:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:103)[150:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:112)[150:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:147)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:69)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)[:1.7.0_01]
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)[:1.7.0_01]
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory.openSessionFromDataSource(DefaultSqlSessionFactory.java:83)[280:org.mybatis.mybatis:3.2.5]
        ... 32 more

Bean.xml

```
<bean id="ds" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
     <property name="driverClass"  value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/> 
     <property name="jdbcUrl" value=""/> 
     <property name="user" value=""/> 
     <property name="password" value="" /> 
</bean> 

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
   <argument ref="ds" />
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mybatisConfig" class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource"> 
    <argument value="SqlMapConfig.xml" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactoryBean" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/> 
    <property name="configLocation" ref="mybatisConfig"/>  
    <property name="mapperLocations">
        <array value-type="org.springframework.core.io.Resource">
             <bean class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">  
                <argument value="mappings/QueryMessaging.xml" />  
             </bean> 

        </array>
    </property> 
</bean> 

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory" factory-ref="sqlSessionFactoryBean" 
    factory-method="getObject" />

<bean id="myBatis" class="org.apache.camel.component.mybatis.MyBatisComponent">
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean> 



<bean id="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="txManager"/>
    <property name="propagationBehaviorName" value="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: It looks like there's no `environment` setup for mybatis. Perhaps the datasource was not setup correctly. Did you set a proper jdbcUrl?

Comment: As we are creating connection from this bean.xml, we have not define any <environment> in SqlMapConfig.xml, if I create connection thru SqlMapConfig.xml, its working.

Comment: I've noticed that you are explicitly calling `getObject` on the `SqlSessionFactoryBean`. This looks incorrect. Since `SqlSessionFactoryBean` implements the `FactoryBean` Spring interface, the bean will already be of the type `SqlSessionFactory`. Refer to docs for examples

Comment: SqlSessionFactoryBean creates session but in my case I have to create bean for `MyBatisComponent` which is used in camel routue. I have checked in camel mybatis, mostly suggested ideas & codes looks like the above one.

Comment: This looks similar to [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045264/camel-mybatis-apache-aries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connections and configurations are created properly, the bug I have made was in bean.xml i have used `myBatis` bean id, and camel route i have type as `mybatis`, due to case-sensitive, no environment was created, sorry for that.